# SVG clippath animation not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I am working on SVG animations. Completed that development part. which is working on Chrome but not working on Firefox. I think inside of 1`clippath` tag path was not taking height and width. Here is the live example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3ge5m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss). 
I have attached below HTML and SCSS snippets. Please have a look.

**HTML code**

```
<svg width="710px" height="231px" viewBox="0 0 710 231">
                            <!-- Generator: Sketch 53.2 (72643) - https://sketchapp.com  -->
                            <title>Chart_IncreaseInAttacks</title>
                            <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
                            <defs>
                                <clipPath id="clip-path-increaseinattacks" class="graph-clipath active">
                                    <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-100%)
                                        width="505"
                                        d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
                                        id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                                    <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-100%)
                                        width="505"
                                        d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
                                        id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                                    <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-100%)
                                        width="505"
                                        d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
                                        id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                                </clipPath>
                            </defs>
                            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                <g id="ATT-CS-Report02_SecurityRiskLandscape"
                                    transform="translate(-245.000000, -440.000000)">
                                    <g id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" transform="translate(245.000000, 440.000000)">
                                        <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-14" fill="#F6F6F6" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0" y="0"
                                            width="710" height="231"></rect>
                                        <text id="Increase-in-attacks"
                                             font-size="15"
                                            font-weight="bold" line-spacing="22" fill="#009FDB">
                                            <tspan x="42" y="40">Increase in attacks in 2018</tspan>
                                        </text>
                                        <text id="Ransomware-attacks"
                                             font-size="11"
                                            font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
                                            <tspan x="68.462" y="83">Ransomware </tspan>
                                            <tspan x="96.765" y="97">attacks</tspan>
                                        </text>
                                        <text id="Spear-phishing-attac"
                                             font-size="11"
                                            font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
                                            <tspan x="58.199" y="167">Spear-phishing </tspan>
                                            <tspan x="96.765" y="181">attacks</tspan>
                                        </text>
                                        <text id="Spoofing/BEC-attacks"
                                             font-size="11"
                                            font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
                                            <tspan x="83.301" y="125">Spoofing/</tspan>
                                            <tspan x="74.27" y="139">BEC attacks</tspan>
                                        </text>
                                        <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
                                            d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
                                            id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                                        <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
                                            d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
                                            id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                                        <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
                                            d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
                                            id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                                        <path d="M150.5,68.5 L150.5,190" id="Line-3-Copy" stroke="#191919"
                                            stroke-linecap="square" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                                        <text id="350%" 
                                            font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
                                            <tspan x="159" y="90">350%</tspan>
                                        </text>
                                        <text id="250%" 
                                            font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
                                            <tspan x="159" y="132">250%</tspan>
                                        </text>
                                        <text id="70%" 
                                            font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
                                            <tspan x="159" y="174">70%</tspan>
                                        </text>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
```

**SCSS code**

```
@mixin delayAnim(){
    $duration: .3s;
    &:nth-child(1){ 
        animation-delay: 0 * $duration;
    }
    &:nth-child(2){
        animation-delay: 1 * $duration;
    }
    &:nth-child(3){
        animation-delay: 2 * $duration;
    }
    &:nth-child(4){
        animation-delay: 3 * $duration;
    }
    &:nth-child(5){
        animation-delay: 4 * $duration;
    }
    &:nth-child(6){
        animation-delay: 5 * $duration;
    }
    &:nth-child(7){
        animation-delay: 6 * $duration;
    }
    &:nth-child(8){
        animation-delay: 7 * $duration;
    }
    &:nth-child(9){
        animation-delay: 8 * $duration;
    }
}

@keyframes drawinx {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

#clip-path-increaseinattacks.active {
   & path{
        animation: drawinx 1s ease-in;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        @include delayAnim();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use SMIL rather than CSS animations.

Comment: @RobertLongson  can you provide me an example for the above provided SVG

Comment: Thank Robert Longson. will catch you soon

Comment: @RobertLongson, FYI Question has been updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it using SMIL animations:
I'm using `fill="freeze"` for `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` and `calcMode="spline"
 keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"`
instead of `ease-in`

```html
<svg width="710px" height="231px" viewBox="0 0 710 231">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 53.2 (72643) - https://sketchapp.com  -->
<title>Chart_IncreaseInAttacks</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clip-path-increaseinattacks" class="graph-clipath active">
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="0s"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform = translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="0.3s"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69" 
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="0.6s"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
 </clipPath>
</defs>
 <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <g id="ATT-CS-Report02_SecurityRiskLandscape" transform="translate(-245.000000, -440.000000)">
  <g id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" transform="translate(245.000000, 440.000000)">
  <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-14" fill="#F6F6F6" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0" y="0" width="710" height="231"></rect>
  <text id="Increase-in-attacks" font-size="15" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="22" fill="#009FDB">
  <tspan x="42" y="40">Increase in attacks in 2018</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Ransomware-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="68.462" y="83">Ransomware </tspan>
  <tspan x="96.765" y="97">attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Spear-phishing-attac" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="58.199" y="167">Spear-phishing</tspan>
  <tspan x="96.765" y="181">attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Spoofing/BEC-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="83.301" y="125">Spoofing/</tspan>
  <tspan x="74.27" y="139">BEC attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  
   
    
    <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" id="kk"
  d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
  id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero"> </path>
  <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
  d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
  id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
  <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
   d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
   id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    
    
    
    
   <path d="M150.5,68.5 L150.5,190" id="Line-3-Copy" stroke="#191919" stroke-linecap="square" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
   <text id="350%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
   <tspan x="159" y="90">350%</tspan>
   </text>
   <text id="250%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
    <tspan x="159" y="132">250%</tspan>
   </text>
   <text id="70%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
   <tspan x="159" y="174">70%</tspan>
   </text>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @enxaneta, Thanks for your answer, but in IE11 chart is not rendering (in IE11 chart would render without animation is also fine.)

Comment: @PavanKumarIdapalapati Use [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) for IE support of SMIL, but your question was about Firefox, not IE.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. added the Fakesmile js. working fine!

Comment: @enxaneta, can we change the `begin` attribute so that it animates only after some event like after itself being added a class name something like that?

Comment: @SaiUnique if you've other questions I suggest you ask them separately.

Comment: You can use one of these events: `click, mousedown, mouseup, mouseover, mousemove, mouseout`. You can also combine events and time: `begin="click+2s"`

Comment: @RobertLongson  can I retrigger this animation throw js ?

Comment: If you want, yes. See [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662876/svg-clippath-animation-not-working-on-firefox/55663551?noredirect=1#comment98017235_55663551).